# How to properly busy wait on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, busy-waiting

I need to implement busy waiting.

If you think I shouldn’t, please provide a low latency alternative to busy waiting for [ID3D11DeviceContext::GetData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-getdata) to return `S_OK` which works on Windows 7 SP1.

I’ve found [KeStallExecutionProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-kestallexecutionprocessor?redirectedfrom=MSDN) API which does exactly what I need. Is that API exposed to user mode? If no, how it’s implemented? I know how to call `_mm_pause` intrinsic, what I don’t know is how to measure time with sufficient precision: `QueryPerformanceCounter` is too expensive for busy waiting, `GetTickCount` is cheap but doesn’t have the resolution I need, and `_rdtsc` may scale with CPU frequency.

**Update #1:** I can stall the CPU just fine, e.g. `for ( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) _mm_pause();` That’s what I’m doing now for a while, before starting to call `Sleep( 1 )` in the outer loop instead.

**Update #2:** Proper waiting for GPU was only implemented in Windows 10 1703 “Creators Update”, see [ID3D11Device5::CreateFence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_4/nf-d3d11_4-id3d11device5-createfence) and [ID3D11Fence::SetEventOnCompletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11_3/nf-d3d11_3-id3d11fence-seteventoncompletion) APIs. In Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 before 1703, busy waiting is the only way to get notified. And I need to be notified ASAP, every millisecond counts. I only have 16ms to render a frame in time, some users have 144Hz displays making it just 7ms on their PCs.

Comment: To properly wait in user mode, see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/wait-functions).

Comment: @PickleRick See the updates